# what to do when name is empty the code gets stuck

Tags: c#

```
public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set 
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Name can not be empty");

                name = value; 
                NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }
```

what to do when name is empty the code gets stuck at name= value .....does not shows message.
what should be done?

Comment: You can check it in get{}

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? What do you want to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Are you referring to debugging after exception occurs?

Comment: What do you expect when null or empty string is assigned to Name? You don't want to see the exception?

Comment: You should probably employ some business logic that validates the object or the properties of the object as needed instead of validating in a set or get. See DataAnnotations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3332507 If had your question answered, would you mark one the replies as an answer?

Comment: Any answer worthy as accepted here?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 public string Name
 {
   get 
    { 
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
       {
         throw new ArgumentException("Name can not be empty");
       }
      return name;
     }
   set { name = value; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to stop the application execution in cases where name is null or empty, then by all means, throw an exception in property setter. It's not "forbidden"... but in most cases I would put the validation of properties somewhere else.

This is because if you do throw an exception then things might blow up, or you can "get stuck", as you put it. Also, if you need to reuse your model in different scenario, where properties are the same but name could be empty, what would you do then?

I don't know if your scenario involves UI or not but you can use ValidationRules to check the validity of properties and give cues to user via UI bindings.

Let's say you have a simple User model consisting of only name and age properties.

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _name;
    private int _age;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now, you want to chekc that yes, the name is actually not null nor empty string. Then you could create simple validation rule to check for this.

```
public class NameLengthRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string name = value as string;
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ? new ValidationResult(false, "Name can't be empty") : new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

Now when you have these in place, and you have instance of type User in your DataContext, you can use the user input and rule on your UI side (assuming it's WPF) like so.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">Invalid value!</TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="validationError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource validationError}" Margin="150">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="User.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:NameLengthRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Which gives you the following on valid input

[image: valid]

and the following on invalid input

[image: invalid]